# Open and extract .sbf files

Tags: android

I have backed up my messages from my Sony Xperia, and now I want to open the file and export them to excel or something more easy to read, but I can't find a program or tool to do that
I just have the file and i want to open it and extract especific information.
I need some help, thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Please consider using http://android.stackexchange.com or another site for end-user questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a utility called `MotoAndroidDepacker` (Google it) - I used it to unpack sbf files for Motorola phones. I'm not sure if it will work in your case, but it's worth giving a try.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer, but the utility can't open the file. The error it throwed was This sbf is not supported